# unmet dependencies of mongodb

Tags: dependencies

I cannot install any other application in Ubuntu.
I have tried all the online mentioned solutions, but none of them are working for me.

Error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: it may seem a similar question but solution mentioned on other pages are not working for my problem.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the problem?